# Song search and stream preview API

Tags: api

Is there an API where I can search for a song, and then stream the preview of the song on my site?

Looked into Amazon MP3, but I  can't seem to find an API for Amazon MP3.

Also looked into last.fm Track.Search api, but seems like the return value doesn't seem to give the actual filename. (i.e mp3 etc), which means I can't stream it on my site.

Please let me know if there are other different APIs I can use as well.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 8):

Hopefully you got sorted for this but just in case (and for future searchers)

[EchoNest](http://echonest.com) has a solid api with will give you 30 sec. track previews

for example:

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=N6E4NIOVYMTHNDM8J&format=json&results=1&artist=radiohead&title=karma%20police&bucket=id:7digital-US&bucket=audio_summary&bucket=tracks

Just a note that it uses 7digital so only tracks in there catalogs will have previews

Comment: EchoNest links aren't working at the time of this comment. Look at the ones from 7digital

Answer (score 6):

Here's the link to the 7digital public API for track search

http://developer.7digital.com/resources/api-docs/catalogue-api#track/search

and here's track preview:

http://developer.7digital.com/resources/api-docs/media-delivery-api#clip/{trackId}

You'll need to register for an API key here:

http://access.7digital.com/partnerprogram

*In the interests of full disclosure I'll mention that I work for 7digital.

Comment: The first two links don't really work any longer, and the "preview" seems to be missing.

Comment: clip preview link doesn't seem to work perfectly, use the left nav to scroll to the appropriate part.

Comment: I signed up for an API key weeks ago via email and received no reply. Is 7digital still relevant?

Answer (score 3):

[Amazon Associates has a "widget" that allows you to play the sample clips from their extensive MP3 library](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/promo/digital.html). However, I can't speak as to how flexible or programmable it is... but at least the link will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

itunes has a search api and preview and album art... they have restrictions (ie, you have to put the "buy on iTunes" badge linking to the song near the preview)...

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: As well one restriction if you want to use for example the game: "(v) is not used for independent entertainment value apart from its promotional purpose;"